# How to return a record with its relation only if the relation has not been deelted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and have some relationships between my models setup.

I have a `Product` model and a `Customer` model (a product has a customer).
I am using the following to get a list of customers, however I am also using soft deletes. If the customer has been soft deleted (the relation), I don't want to return the product.

How do I achieve this in Laravel?

`$products = Product::with('customer')->get();` --want to say "where customer.deleted_at is null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `has` on the query:

`$products = Product::with('customer')->has('customer')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

As @Lock put it, use

```
$products = Product::with('customer')->has('customer')->get();
```

TIP: For the opposite - i.e to get only the products with deleted customers (doesn't make much sense here but you may find this handy in future), use below

```
$deleted=Product::with(['customer' => function ($q) {
    $q->withTrashed();
    }])->onlyTrashed()->get();
```